# What is the difference between Kafka Cluster setup and multi node set up

Tags: configuration, apache-kafka, cluster-computing

Wanted to understand the difference between Kafka multimode setup and Multi cluster environment.

Please correct me if I am wrong:

Kafka Multi Node Set Up: I have 2 zookeeper nodes {z1,z2} communicating to each other and 3 Kafka brokers nodes {K1,k2,k3} configure to z1 and z2. Here if I register a producer and consumer then all K1,K2,K3 will share the load.

I have 2 different Kafka Multi Node Set Up KMNS1,KMNS2

Kafka Multi Cluster Set Up: I have 2 different {Kafka Multi Node Set Up} {KMNS1,KMNS2}. Here 2 different team can use the single {Kafka Multi Node Set Up} KMNS1 without impacting other set up KMNS2.

Please confirm my understanding is correct or not?

In Kafka Multi Cluster Set Up KMNS1's {Z1,Z2,K1,K2,K3} should not be known about KMNS2's {ZZ1,ZZ2,KK1,KK2,KK3}?

In a company 3 different team using Kafka. Can we set up one KMNS1 setup and ask every team to use the same, or we should have 3 different  setup like KMNS1,KMNS2,KMNS3. What is the best practice need to be followed ?

Is there any performance impact or some other issue except security policies, if 3 different  team use the same KMNS1 set up?
Does one application failure impact other performance ?

Comment: Where did you find those terms ' multi cluster Kafka set up'?
Do you use same zk nodes with your K1' K2' and K3'? Same physical boxes? If no, yeah you have two distinct cluster, each one not being able to impact the other

Comment: Thanks for quick  response  @Yannick.
Is there any differences  if all deployments  are in same box or different  boxes?

Comment: @Yannick In a company 3 different team using Kafka. Can we set up one KMNS1 setup and ask every team to use the same, or we should have 3 different  setup like KMNS1,KMNS2,KMNS3. What is the best practice need to be followed ?

Comment: You can run multiple cluster using same boxes of course , just make sure to not mess up with interfaces. Regarding your second question, 3 different teams can use the same cluster, it's all regarding what security policies you have in your company, or operational organization

Comment: Thanks again @Yannick. Just one last clarification Is there any performance impact or some other issue except security policies if 3 different team use the same KMNS1 set up? Does one application failure (due to issue in MSG consumer not able consume and after some retry one consumer is failed  )impact other performance ?

Comment: In Kafka, producers and consumers are not coupled together, you won't have any backpressure issue ( Kafka will keep all the records for 7 days by default in all cases), nor consumers can impact performance of other consumers ( in other consumer group). That being said, care about scaling, if your 3 teams ask a lot in term of performance, be sure to have enough brokers to absorb the load